# jQuery tmpl .appendTo gives "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

The following code works fine everywhere except from VA hospitals.  It works on all major browsers, except when at VA hospitals.  I can see the ajax call goes out, it comes back with all of the data, but when it hits to .appendTo() line, it doesn't work.  I get this error:

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jQuery/jquery-tmpl-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetPlayers() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "wsPlayers.asmx/GetPlayers",

            dataType: "json",

            type: "POST",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: ("{paramMinChampionships: " + $("#selChamps").val() + "}"),

            error: function (err) {

                alert("Error:" + err.responseText);

            },

            success: function (results) { OnComplete(results.d) }



        });

    }



    function OnComplete(results) {

        $("#tbodyPlayers").empty();  //We want to clear the body of the table first.

        $("#playerDataTemplate").tmpl(results).appendTo("#tbodyPlayers");

    }



</script>
```

The error returned is:

"Line: 30
Char 4
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code: 0
URL: http://vatest.docphin.com/"

Line 30 is: $("#playerDataTemplate").tmpl(results).appendTo("#tbodyPlayers");

You can view the site at http://vatest.docphin.com

Again, the error ONLY occurs at VA Hospitals, not anywhere else.

Comment: Can you please screenshot the output of placing `console.log(results);` above line 30?  I can see that it works fine in the link, so I am sure it has to do with the response from the server being malformed.

Comment: @PranayRana It is a templating engine used with jQuery, like Mustache.

Comment: Sure it's not the `tmpl()` method that's not supported for whatever reason? And why are you using `tmpl()`? Beta features make me nervous... :/

Comment: This is the template code:`<script id="playerDataTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

    <tr>

        <td>${firstname}</td>

  <td>${lastname}</td>

  {{if championships>0}}

      <td align="center"><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">${championships}</span></td>

  {{else}}

      <td align="center">${championships}</td>

  {{/if}}

  <td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.bing.com/search?q=${firstname}+${lastname}">search</a></td>

    </tr>

</script>`

Comment: I'm not at a VA hospital, so it works fine for me.  If I do console.log, it'll be fine.  I can have a doc try it at the VA, but not sure when I'll be able to arrange that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, at the VA, if the initial browser session is SSL, all the rest of the ajax calls within the page have to be SSL.  The VA hospititals are the only places I've seen this occur.

More info can be found here:
http://www.jonwear.com/2012/02/trouble-with-jquery-tmpl-plugin.html